# When do I need to restart nginx

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

When do I need to restart nginx when using with django and uwsgi?
In case when templates are changed, static files are changed or any other reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably only when you change its configuration, if you are referring to when your django code changes you have to restart the uwsgi server, usually "touch"ing the wsgi.py file is enough to instruct the uwsgi server.

Changes in static files don't require the uwsgi restart (because you usually serve them directly with nginx), and if you don't use [cached template loaders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader), but only the default filesystem loader, you don't require the restart when changing a template either.

Note that the cached template loader is *usually* suggested in production.

Comment: when using cached template loaders *.html change -> uwsgi restart or nginx restart?

Comment: uwsgi! :)  , that will force django to reload the templates into memory.